# How do I uninstall Setapp when iStat is running?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to uninstall the Setapp. I was going to think about renewing my subscription later but it forced my hand because iStat constantly pops up a windows that says:

> Your Setapp subscription is no longer active, and iStat Menus Status cannot be opened.

If I cancel, quit, drag to the trash or `kill` iStat it always comes back. So now I'm trying to uninstall Setapp but I'm running into the same problem. The uninstall dialog wants me to quit iStat but no amount of hitting the 'Quit' button will make iStat go away and thus I can't uninstall Setapp.

Comment: Try force unloading the three bjango.istat* launch agents first: `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bjango.istatmenusagent.plist` (the other two are com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications and com.bjango.istatmenusstatus). `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bjango.istat*` may also work.

Comment: This did it, though I had to use `sudo launchctl bootout gui/501 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bjango.istat*` instead.

Comment: man. what a mess. Is this really how to uninstall setapp??

Comment: fuck setapp.  It was toxic to get it off my system.  Try these commands:

`pkill -9 -i "setapp*"`

`launchctl unload com.setapp.DesktopClient.SetappAgent`

`launchctl unload com.setapp.DesktopClient.SetappUpdater.plist`

`rm -rf  ~/Library/Application\ Support/Setapp/`

`rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.setapp.DesktopClient.SetappAgent.FinderSyncExt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iStat Menus is a little different to other apps, in that it is intended to always be running and in your menubar. The main app is used to configure its settings. Throwing the main app in the trash won’t remove it from your system (we wish it could, but that’s not technically possible).

The normal way to uninstall iStat Menus is to choose iStat Menus → Uninstall from the menubar inside the iStat Menus app, then click Uninstall.

We have some additional help: [Installing and uninstalling iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus5/install/)

For those using Setapp, here’s some specific instructions.

#### Uninstalling iStat Menus *with* an active Setapp account

If you have an active Setapp account, please choose `iStat Menus` → `Uninstall` from the menubar, then click Uninstall.

#### Uninstalling iStat Menus *without* an active Setapp account

If you don’t have an active Setapp account, please run `/Library/Application Support/iStat Menus 5/iStat Menus Uninstaller.app`

You can get to the uninstaller by choosing `Go` → `Go to Folder` while in the Finder, then pasting `/Library/Application Support/iStat Menus 5/iStat Menus Uninstaller.app` into the text field and clicking Go.

If you have any other questions about iStat Menus, or need more help with uninstalling, please don’t hesitate to get in touch [via our website](https://bjango.com/contact/), [via Twitter](https://twitter.com/bjango), or via any other means.

Clarification: I work on iStat Menus. I am a founder and designer at Bjango.

Comment: It is not a pleasant experience for the user to be punished like that just because we do not want to pay you after the trial is ended. I had to spend quite some time to clean away all of the nasty SetApp items before I could start working again after a reboot.

This process made it clear for me that i will never trust you again, I was planning on paying but just wanted to see if how I would get by without the apps for a week first.

Comment: @Johan I'm not sure you understand how apps like this work. It's technically infeasible to uninstall an app like iStat Menus just by dragging it to the Trash — it installs daemons so that you don't have to keep the configuration app open all the time. Also be aware that Marc is from Bjango (iStat Menus dev), not Setapp. iStat Menus is a fantastic app I've used daily for years.

Comment: @grgarside I have not said anything about moving iStat to trash. So please staty to the topic. But yes, my unpleasant situation was caused by how SetApp handles the end of trial and not by the iStat app itself, and I was not aware of who Marc is working for or not. Do you claim that SetApp who installed this app on my computer could not have uninstalled it when the trial was over? This was however not the only app from SetApp that slammed up blocking popups and messed with my system. Even the background picture from space one disappeared, crazy =)

Comment: @grgarside you're talking like iStatis unique in this regard. I used plenty of apps that live in the app bar, some of which include kernel components - VPNs, osxfuse, caffeine, 1pass, spectacle,alfred, and so on and so on, and all of them can be deleted just by moving app to trash. All of them! Your app is the only one giving me trouble, and I do regret the day I installed it. Please quit excusing your own incompetence by saying it is 'not technically infeasible''

Comment: @letitbee Allow me to preface once again and say this is not my app, and I am not the author of this answer. With regard to the apps you mention: I'm not sure what you mean by VPNs since they are added in System Preferences, I haven't a clue what OSXFUSE app you're removing but [there's no way trashing the app is a proper uninstallation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXNWk.png), and Caffeine/1Password/Spectacle/Alfred are all perfectly standard apps so I don't know why you are comparing them in this situation.

Comment: @grgarside my bad, I confused you with Marco. Not your incompetence, his, please accept my apologies. Now, to apps: no, not all VPNs live in prefs, some, like PIA, have own apps, and they are managing routing tables and virtual devices. Caffeine uses a kernel module (funny as it is), this is what it takes under OSX. Regardless, all of this has actually zero to do with (un)install procedure. It's ok(-ish) to leave code lying around after uninstall, it's absolutely deplorable and unprecedented when you can't actually delete the goddamn thing without knowledge of terminal and OSX folder layouts.

Comment: @letitbee The difference with those other apps is: iStat Menus runs on startup via a daemon, and the main app doesn’t have to be running or shown in the dock. That’s the main reason, not that it’s a menubar app. We could definitely make it possible for iStat Menus to be deleted by dragging it to the trash, but not while keeping the way it works now. There were some other reasons as well, but newer versions of macOS have resolved those, so they’re not a concern now.

Answer (score 3):

Running this commands should solve your issue, right after quitting the app

```
rm -rf  ~/Library/Application\ Support/Setapp/
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.setapp.DesktopClient.SetappAgent.FinderSyncExt
```

This would never popup again.

Answer (score 1):

that's Volodymyr from Setapp team here.

You see, the iStat Menus app has its own uninstallation procedure to remove its app agents due to their installation to the Launch Agents.

To uninstall iStat Menus completely, please navigate to the ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder (or the /Library/LaunchAgents folder, depending on the version of iStat Menus you had), and remove the following leftovers to uninstall iStat Menus completely:

com.bjango.istatmenusagent.plist 
com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications.plist 
com.bjango.istatmenusstatus.plist

At Setapp we're working on the smooth uninstallation procedure, hope to have the update soon.

Have a great day.

Comment: So it's impossible to uninstall setapp atm?

Comment: @Mauran Did you read the answer? It provides the uninstallation instructions. Also see the [other answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276315/37797) from iStat Menus dev.